# Dissolve shapefile and summarize text fields

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dissolve

I have a polygon shapefile that I would like to dissolve on a field called FID_merged (see below). For each dissolved polygon I would like to summarize a list of the countries.

I am using ArcGIS 10.3 and see that the only option for text-field statistics are first and last. How could dissolve on FID_merged and still maintain a list of all the countries for that FID_merged?

I am open to other non-esri solutions.

[image]

Comment: Are you open to using python?

Comment: I would be open to using python. This seems like a common situation and we might as well come up with a few different approaches.